# error on running my application in Django with mod_python

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-python

I have win32,python2.5,django1.2, apache2.2, and mod_python3.3.1

I have installed properly mod_python.
Now my application name is myapp.setting which path is c:\myapp.setting. In myapp.settings my file is myapp.settings\url.py,settings.py etc.

now in apache httpd.conf file I have changes following:-

```
<Location "/mysite">
    SetHandler python-program
    PythonHandler django.core.handlers.modpython
    SetEnv DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE myapp.settings
    PythonDebug On
    PythonPath "['/'] + sys.path"
</Location>
```

and I have tried many changes in PythonPath. but when i typed http://localhost/mysite the error is following:-

MOD_PYTHON ERROR

```
ProcessId:      1384
Interpreter:    '192.168.1.166'

ServerName:     '192.168.1.166'
DocumentRoot:   'C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/htdocs'

URI:            '/mysite'
Location:       '/mysite'
Directory:      None
Filename:       'C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/htdocs/mysite'
PathInfo:       ''

Phase:          'PythonHandler'
Handler:        'django.core.handlers.modpython'

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Python25\Lib\site-packages\mod_python\importer.py", line 1537, in HandlerDispatch
    default=default_handler, arg=req, silent=hlist.silent)

  File "C:\Python25\Lib\site-packages\mod_python\importer.py", line 1229, in _process_target
    result = _execute_target(config, req, object, arg)

  File "C:\Python25\Lib\site-packages\mod_python\importer.py", line 1128, in _execute_target
    result = object(arg)

  File "C:\Python25\Lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\modpython.py", line 228, in handler
    return ModPythonHandler()(req)

  File "C:\Python25\Lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\modpython.py", line 191, in __call__
    self.load_middleware()

  File "C:\Python25\Lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 33, in load_middleware
    for middleware_path in settings.MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES:

  File "C:\Python25\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 276, in __getattr__
    self._setup()

  File "C:\Python25\Lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 40, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)

  File "C:\Python25\Lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 75, in __init__
    raise ImportError("Could not import settings '%s' (Is it on sys.path? Does it have syntax errors?): %s" % (self.SETTINGS_MODULE, e))

ImportError: Could not import settings 'myapp.settings' (Is it on sys.path? Does it have syntax errors?): No module named myapp.settings
```

Please help me I am new in Django...

Comment: You call your project `myapp.settings`? This is wrong, your app should be called app and settings.py should be file in the project, the way it is now settings are probably located in `myapp.settings.settings`, and  you can't have dot in package names in python AFAIK.

Comment: thanks for suggestion I have changed my application name myapp.settings to myapp. But it still give an error "ImproperlyConfigured: Error importing middleware myproject.FacebookConnectMiddleware: "No module named myproject.FacebookConnectMiddleware"
I want to use facebook connect in a site.

Comment: `myproject.FacebookConnectMiddleware` is probably in some file inside `myproject` so insert that files name in the module path. Something like: `myproject.filename.FacebookConnectMiddleware`. `myproject.FacebookConnectMiddleware` makes it look like the actual middleware code is in projects `__init__.py`

Answer (score 2):

As rebus says in his comment, it's nonsense to call your project 'myapp.settings'. It's neither an app (which is a component of a site), nor is it a settings file. Call it something sensible - if you really can't think of anything, call it 'mysite'.

Finally, however, you should not be using mod_python. Use mod_wsgi instead.

Comment: thanks Daniel but if you can give me the solution in mod_python then it will ease for me......

Comment: @rohitbansal2009 mod_python is no longer being actively developed so you can't expect any high quality support for it. Also you have several problems with your project and best way to start amending them is, as suggested in the answer, to rename your project to something sensible, perhaps the mod_python problem will be no longer after that or you will have clearer picture of what's wrong.